# Is there a way to get requestor info in C# apiController

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I'm using microsoft's APIController in a web api, I'd like to see information about the requestor, such as the IP and whatever other info about requestor I can find out. IE

```
public class ExampleController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    [HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage GetStuff(HttpRequestMessage message)
    {
        //get info about caller, maybe using
        //HttpContext.Current.Request. something
        var requestorIP = ????
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you using ASP.NET Core or the older ASP.NET 5?

Comment: @DavidG You mean ASP.NET 4?

Comment: @mason Haha yes, god these version numbers are such a pain

Comment: @mason Wait, no, it is MVC 5 isn't it? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET_MVC#Release_history

Comment: @DavidG Well it'd be ASP.NET 4, but MVC 5, and ASP.NET Web API 2. MVC's version number isn't really relevant though, as one can use ASP.NET Web API 2 on .NET framework without having any of the MVC specific bits.

Comment: Either way, there are already dozens of questions on how to do this.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

It looks like you can get the remote IP address through [`Context.Connection.RemoteIpAddress`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.connectioninfo?view=aspnetcore-2.2), the remote port is also on the connection object.